# Civilization 6: Civic's tree doesn't appear after latest patch

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-6

Anyone else experiencing a bug in the game, where the Civic's tree doesn't appear?

With the civics tree not appearing I cannot make any progress onto the next turn.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csaOa.jpg

Everything else is working fine - this has only started happening since the latest patch - was wondering if anyone has a workaround

Comment: Only thing you can do is try and remove/uninstall any mods and verify the integrity of your game files to see if it starts working. If not you'll have to wait for them to fix it since the cause is clearly the recent patch. Many people have been experiencing various issues; I would expect a hotfix eventually.

Comment: In the thread https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/58q3qj/psa_guide_on_how_to_enable_wasd_andor_other/ there's a section titled "Clicking the blue "CHOOSE CIVIC" icon in the bottom right of the screen opens the Civics Tree in addition to the Civics Panel:" Does switching between the side panel/tree solve your issue?